# Maven : Does all Dependencies in DependenciesManagenent and Plugins in PluginManagement also inherit by the child?

Tags: java, apache, maven, plugins, dependencies

I know the child inherits the dependecies of the parent dependency management. My question is why do I still need to explicity indicate the inherited dependecies in the child?

In plugin management. does plugin inside the plugin management also inherits by the child?

Answer (score 0):

Dependency management in the parent pom is designed for uniformity. Plugin management also has the same purpose.

Let's use the scenario of a parent pom (P) with 2 modules (A and B).
Both A and B require spring-boot library.
A requires mongodb library, but not B.

So A explicitly inherit spring-boot and mongodb; B explicitly inherit just spring-boot. While inheriting, it's common to not include the  and implicitly inherit that from the parent.